# Error handling for jQuery ajax load()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, error-handling

I am loading ajax load

```
function ajaxPageFilter(filterDiv, filterLink, filterName, loaderDivId, loaderId) {
        jQuery("#" + filterDiv).load(filterLink, {'filterName': filterName}, function(data) {
            jQuery("img.lazy").lazyload({effect : "fadeIn"});
            jQuery('#'+loaderDivId).remove();
            jQuery('#'+loaderId).remove();
        });
    }
```

Is there a way to do error handling for ajax load, in case if it fails.

thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can capture the `status` argument in your callback, and have a condition to check if there is an error.

```
jQuery("#" + filterDiv).load(filterLink, {'filterName': filterName}, function(data, status) {
    if(status == "error"){
        // do something
    } else {
        jQuery("img.lazy").lazyload({effect : "fadeIn"});
        jQuery('#'+loaderDivId).remove();
        jQuery('#'+loaderId).remove();
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks .. found example here as well I will try your code http://api.jquery.com/load/#example-1